# How to switch Angular Tab in a Cypress Test

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress

I have a Signup/Signin Angular Material Form

```html
  <mat-tab-group class="signupDiv">
    <mat-tab label="Sign Up">
      <app-signup></app-signup>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab id="idTabSignIn" label="Signin">
      <app-signin></app-signin>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

I want to build a cypress test like

1. Switch Tab to Signin.
2. Fill Form.
3. Click Sign in.

two and three is no Problem, but I struggle with 1. How I can switch the tab with Cypress?

My code so far

```js
describe('Signin', () => {
  it('Sign with existing account', function () {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('#idTabSignIn').click()   <---ERROR: idTabSignIn not found
  })
})
```

Update:
Finally i solved it with

```
  it('Sign with existing account', function () {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('.mat-tab-label').contains("Signin").click()
    cy.get('#idEmailSignIn').type(this.testUserData.email)
    cy.get('#idPasswordSignIn').type(this.testUserData.password)
    cy.get('#idSignInButton').click()
  })
```

Comment: Can you add the error screenshot to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular Material library does not propagate attributes like id or data-cy through to the running page, so Cypress is unable to use them.

This is what you see in dev-tools

```html
<div class="mat-tab-label-content">Signin</div>
```

IMO the best approach is based on the label text which is moved from the attribute in source to element content on the page.

```js
cy.contains('div.mat-tab-label-content', 'Signin').click()
```

There can be multiple versions of the tab if you have responsive variations (desktop, mobile), so you may need strengthen the selector context, for example

```js
cy.contains('mat-tab-group.signupDiv div.mat-tab-label-content', 'Signin').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Cypress are you using?

Presuming it is the latest version there are two ways to approach this problem both with a common first step.

Common first step:

1. Change your HTML code to include the data-cy attribute like so:

```
<mat-tab data-cy="id-tab-sign-in" id="idTabSignIn" label="Signin">
      <app-signin></app-signin>
</mat-tab>
```

And then approach number one:

1. Start your cypress runner with watcher. Typically it is `ng e2e --watch`
2. [image]
   Click on the `+ New Spec File` button.
3. Name your spec file.
4. Point and click your test and click save when done.

You can now open this auto-generated test in your IDE and edit as needed.

Approach number two:

1. Change your code to `cy.get('[data-cy="id-tab-sign-in"]').click();`

Using the data-cy attribute is one of the "best practices" suggested in Cypress documentation. I personally have found the `name` attribute to also be useful when attempting to generate e2e tests which must run on different harnesses (Cypress, Selenium, Appium etc).

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, attributes like `data-cy` do not propagate like this, on `<mat-tab>` in particular, so this is not an appropriate answer to the specific question even if it's a good practice to do in general.